# How to effect a specific CSS location when many share similar classes

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to change a background on a specific page using the cyberchimp's responsive theme.  I have found the page id and am able to change the CSS on each of the locations:

```
.page-id-137

#wrapper
```

If I do a traditional

```
.page-id-137 #wrapper {
   background:blue;
}
```

it changes the the major back ground for the page 137 and the wrappers for all posts.  I want it to just effect the wrapper that is associated with page 137.  Any help with figuring this out would be incredibly helpful.

I tried using ">" to direct to the wrapper, but that didn't work.

EDIT: Added html mark-up.

```
<body class="page page-id-137 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support custom-background">
<div id="container" class="hfeed">
 <div id="header"></div><!-- end of #header -->

 <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
   <div id="content" class="grid col-940">
     <div id="post-137" class="post-137 page type-page status-publish hentry">              
        <h1 class="entry-title post-title">TITLE</h1>
        <div class="post-entry"> CONTENT 
        </div>  
     <div class="post-edit"><a class="post-edit-link" href="http://uofueclub.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=137&amp;action=edit">Edit</a></div>
     </div><!-- end of #post-137 -->
   </div><!-- end of #content -->
 </div><!-- end of #wrapper -->
</div><!-- end of #container -->

<div id="footer" class="clearfix">
</div><!-- end #footer -->

</body>
```

Comment: Can you post the exact HTML markup?

Comment: We would required more info.

Comment: Based on the HTML structure, `.page-id-137 #wrapper { background:blue; }` should work fine for *all* pages with a body class called `.page-id-137`.

Comment: Weird, I tried that earlier and it didn't work, now it is.  Strange thanks!